# How correct to locate the directories and subdirectories and generate all icons of each subdirectory and then to remove the files that already exist?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

#### Sources

- [Add prefix and suffix to every line in a .txt file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434611/add-prefix-and-suffix-to-every-line-in-a-txt-file)
- ['ls -1' : how to list filenames without extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283886/ls-1-how-to-list-filenames-without-extension)
- [Linux commands to fetch all files,size and path of files from all directories and subdirectories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88849/linux-commands-to-fetch-all-files-size-and-path-of-files-from-all-directories-an)
- [Remove files and subdirectories of particular folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226780/remove-files-and-subdirectories-of-particular-folder)
- [How to make a text file in every subdirectory so that the text file contains name of the directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588342/how-to-make-a-text-file-in-every-subdirectory-so-that-the-text-file-contains-nam)

#### Details

My script is based on [@btd1337](https://github.com/btd1337)'s [Uratu Icons script](https://github.com/btd1337/urutau-icons/blob/master/scripts/clean-install.sh) for leaving only the third-party icons, but this script is not compatible with my icons theme project, because:

- [Yaru++](https://github.com/Bonandry/yaru-plus) and Canonical's [Yaru](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru) have different hierarchies/trees;
- Yaru++ uses the format SVG and Yaru uses the format PNG.

So I rewrote a script in Shell Script to locate the directories and subdirectories of original Yaru, generate the output of all icons of each subdirectory to text files, and enter into the Yaru++ folder, list the text files to remove the files that already exist and leave only the third-party icons. I also proivided a compressed file for easing your analysis at the end of detail.

Pay attention to the sample and small trees of Yaru++ and Yaru:

- **Tree of Yaru++:**

  ```
  Yaru++
  ├── actions
  │   ├── 16
  │   │   ├── button_cancel.svg
  │   │   └── window-close.svg
  │   ├── 48
  │   │   ├── button_cancel.svg
  │   │   └── window-close.svg
  │   ├── scalable
  │   │   ├── button_cancel.svg
  │   │   └── window-close.svg
  │   └── symbolic
  │       ├── button_cancel-symbolic.svg
  │       └── window-close-symbolic.svg
  └── apps
      ├── 16
      │   ├── office.svg
      │   └── x-office-address-book.svg
      ├── scalable
      │   ├── office.svg
      │   └── x-office-address-book.svg
      └── symbolic
          ├── office-symbolic.svg
          └── x-office-address-book-symbolic.svg
  ```
- **Tree of original Yaru**:

  ```
  Yaru
  ├── 16x16
  │   ├── actions
  │   │   ├── button_cancel.png
  │   │   └── window-close.png
  │   └── apps
  │       ├── office.png
  │       └── x-office-address-book.png
  ├── 48x48
  │   ├── actions
  │   │   ├── button_cancel.png
  │   │   └── window-close.png
  │   └── apps
  │       ├── office.png
  │       └── x-office-address-book.png
  └── scalable
      ├── actions
      │   ├── button_cancel-symbolic.svg
      │   └── window-close.svg
      └── apps
          ├── officer-symbolic.svg
          └── x-office-address-book-symbolic.svg
  ```

Also pay attention to small details:

- In original Yaru, sizes are folders and directories are subfolders;
- In Yaru++, directories are folders and sizes are subfolders;
- Original Yaru's `scalable/[directories]` is same as Yaru++'s `[directories]/symbolic` because their icons have the suffix `-symbolic`.

Now I'll show each part of script in Shell Script:

Observe that `directories` is the same in both Yaru and Yaru++. The sizes are different.

```bsh
yaru_original="/usr/share/icons/Yaru"
declare -a yaru_original_sizes=(16x16 24x24 32x32 48x48 scalable)

yaru_plus="$HOME/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++"
declare -a yaru_plus_sizes=(16 24 32 48 symbolic)

declare -a directories=(actions apps categories devices emblems mimetypes places status)

home="$(pwd)" # folder /script
```

The next part will locate the original Yaru, its folders (`size`) and subfolders (`directory`), and it will store to `fileList`:

```bsh
echo "PHASE 1 – Locate the directories of original Yaru"

function main() 
{
  cd $yaru_original
  for size in "${yaru_original_sizes[@]}"
  do
      for directory in "${directories[@]}"
      do
          fileList $size $directory
      done
  done
  cd $home
}
```

Then it will return to the original `pwd` where the folder `script` is.

It should output like:

```bsh
# $yaru_original/$size/directory
/usr/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/actions
/usr/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/apps
/usr/share/icons/Yaru/24x24/actions
/usr/share/icons/Yaru/24x24/apps
/usr/share/icons/Yaru/32x32/actions
/usr/share/icons/Yaru/32x32/apps
/usr/share/icons/Yaru/48x48/actions
/usr/share/icons/Yaru/48x48/apps
/usr/share/icons/Yaru/scalable/actions
/usr/share/icons/Yaru/scalable/apps
# ...
```

Then the function `fileList` that stored the subdirectories from the function `main`, and will generate the output of all icons without extension (because Yaru uses the format PNG and Yaru++ uses the format SVG) of each subdirectory:

```bsh
echo "PHASE 2 – Generate output files without extension"

function fileList() 
{
    local directory=$1
    local size=$2
    local search_file=($(find $yaru_original/$size/$directory/))
    if [ $search_file ]
    then
        for entry in "${search_file[@]}"
        do
          for i in *; do echo "${i%.png}"; done > $home/$directory-$size.txt
        done
    fi
}
```

It should output like:

```bsh
# $home/$directory-$size.txt
/home/gus/script/actions-16x16.txt
/home/gus/script/apps-16x16.txt
/home/gus/script/actions-24x24.txt
/home/gus/script/apps-24x24.txt
/home/gus/script/actions-32x32.txt
/home/gus/script/apps-32x32.txt
/home/gus/script/actions-48x48.txt
/home/gus/script/apps-48x48.txt
/home/gus/script/actions-scalable.txt
/home/gus/script/apps-scalable.txt
```

Observe that I do not know to subtract `x{size}` and to replace `scalable` for `symbolic` which is not present in original Yaru's array `yaru_original_sizes`.

Inside a file `actions-16x16.txt`:

```
button_cancel
window-close
```

Now, in the final party, it will read the text files using `awk` and printing the extension `.svg`, and will remove the files that already exist in Yaru, from Yaru++:

```bsh
echo "PHASE 3 – Remove the files that already exist in Canonical's original Yaru"

function removeList()
{
  cd $yaru_plus
  for directory in "${directories[@]}"
  do
      for size in "${yaru_plus_sizes[@]}"
      do
          rm $(awk '{ print $0".svg" }' $home/$size-$directory.txt)
      done
  done
}

main
```

Output of `awk '{ print $0".svg" }' $home/$size-$directory.txt`:

```
# awk '{ print $0".svg" }' /home/gus/script/actions-16x16.txt
button_cancel.svg
window-close.svg
```

Output of `rm $(awk '{ print $0".svg" }' $home/$size-$directory.txt)`:

```
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/actions/16/button_cancel.svg
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/actions/16/window-close.svg
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/actions/48/button_cancel.svg
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/actions/48/window-close.svg
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/actions/symbolic/button_cancel-symbolic.svg
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/actions/symbolic/window-close-symbolic.svg
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/apps/16/office.svg
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/apps/16/x-office-address-book.svg
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/apps/48/office.svg
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/apps/48/x-office-address-book.svg
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/apps/symbolic/office-symbolic.svg
rm /home/gus/GitHub/yaru-plus/Yaru++/apps/symbolic/x-office-address-book-symbolic.svg
```

I will provide a small compressed folder for easing your analysis: https://github.com/Bonandry/yaru-plus/files/5013472/UnixStackExchange.zip

#### Result

The script was unsuccessful because the error output:

```
find: ‘/usr/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/128x128/’: No file or folder
find: ‘/usr/share/icons/Yaru/24x24/128x128/’: No file or folder
find: ‘/usr/share/icons/Yaru/32x32/128x128/’: No file or folder
find: ‘/usr/share/icons/Yaru/48x48/128x128/’: No file or folder
```

My script did not work, and it seemed my codes are not correct. How to locate correctly directories and subdirectories, using function and `for` condition, to store for `fileList` and how to make `fileList` generate correctly the file output with all icons of each subdirectory, and then to remove the files that already exist in Yaru, from Yaru++ and leave only the third-party icons?

Comment: @jsbillings, updated question. I changed to a pure question and added a question at the end of details.

Comment: There is a lot of intermediate stuff here that doesn't seem to be important. I mean, the finaly question could just be "How to remove the files that already exist in Yaru, from Yaru++ and leave only the third-party icons?" Why is the stuff in between needed?

Comment: Also: You seem to be calling `fileList $size $directory`, but in the `fileList` function, you have `local directory=$1` `local size=$2` - why swap the order of arguments?

Comment: Also: why would you do `for entry in "${search_file[@]}"
        do for i in *; do echo "${i%.png}"; done`, ignoring the `entry` altogether?

Comment: @muru. Our project's users are too demanding and want a minimal icons theme with only third-party icons without including all the original Yaru icons, to reduce the file size: https://github.com/Bonandry/yaru-plus/issues/48.

Comment: @muru,

Well `local directory=$1` and `local size=$2` are stored from the function `main`. Ah, it must be that error. I will do a small test, replacing `entry` with `i`.

Comment: Unfortunately the same error as in the result at the end of question detail. :-(

Comment: "Well `local directory=$1` and `local size=$2` are stored from the function `main`" ... what I mean is, you're passing size and directory in that order to the function, but then using them as directory and size in the reverse order. Why is that?

Comment: Because of Yaru++ (`$home/$directory-$size.txt`). It needed to be ordered for outputting the files from original Yaru.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a condensed version that should work:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

yaru_original="/UnixStackExchange/usr/share/icons/Yaru"
yaru_plus="/UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++"

# map the Yaru sizes to Yaru++ sizes
declare -A size_mapping=([16x16]=16 [24x24]=24 [32x32]=32 [48x48]=48 [scalable]=symbolic)
declare -a directories=(actions apps categories devices emblems mimetypes places status)

for size in "${!size_mapping[@]}"
do
    for dir in "${directories[@]}"
    do
        for i in "$yaru_original/$size/$dir/"*.{png,svg}
        do
            # Take just the filename ${i##*/} and build the new path
            plus_file=$yaru_plus/$dir/${size_mapping["$size"]}/${i##*/}
            if [[ $plus_file = *.png ]]
            then
                # replce the extension with svg
                plus_file=${plus_file%.png}.svg
            fi
            [[ -f "$plus_file" ]] && echo rm "$plus_file"
        done
    done
done
```

In the sample given, this detected 13 files out of 50 for removal:

```
# bash foo.sh
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/actions/16/window-close.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/apps/16/office.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/apps/16/x-office-address-book.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/actions/48/window-close.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/apps/48/office.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/apps/48/x-office-address-book.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/actions/symbolic/button-close-symbolic.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/actions/symbolic/window-close-symbolic.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/apps/symbolic/office-symbolic.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/apps/symbolic/x-office-address-book-symbolic.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/actions/24/window-close.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/apps/24/office.svg
rm /UnixStackExchange/home/gus/GitHub/Yaru++/apps/24/x-office-address-book.svg
```

Run the script without `echo` to delete the files. Maybe use `rm -i` instead of `echo rm`.

Comment: I have never heard of multidimensional array in Shell Script, it seems to be very rare. I thought it is exclusive of C, C++, Java, Javascript, PHP and Python.

Comment: @GustavoReis `size_mapping` is not a mutlidimensional array, it's an associative array (like a `dict` in Python or a map in C++). Associative arrays aren't uncommon in bash scripts.